# can't display left column for timeslots with full-calendar & set full-calendar to french language

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails to display an interactive calendar where users will be able to enter availabilities.

My calendar must have a header with days week and a left row with different timeslots. I have been struggling to display left row with different timeslots. This is my actual configuration with fullcalendar :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...

    $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar({
      defaultView: 'basicWeek',
      columnFormat: 'dddd',
      lang: "fr",
      header: false,
      allDaySlot: true,
      timeFormat: 'H:mmtt{-H:mmtt }',
    });

});
```

But I didnt manage to display this left column with time slot as you can see :

[image]
I have also tried to set the calendar in french lang by including

```
//= require fullcalendar/gcal
```

in `application.js` as was suggested in https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails but it doesnt work.

Do you know how to display the left column with timeslots and set the calendar in french ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to display left column for timeslots by actually using

```
defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
```

but still searching for the language problem